# MVVM: Pass Parameter from viewmodel to view

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-store-apps

Im new to MVVM and XAML. Currently the application that I have to extend is some kind of imageviewer. It uses MVVM with a RelayCommand. Currently the code behind file of my XAML-file is almost empty.

Data is displayed with databinding to the viewmodel and user interaction is bound with command to the model.

But now I need to display an image that is an custom control. In XAML I have to place a Border-Control and than the control must be initialized in the code behind file.

My question is how to do the setup when following MVVM.

PseudoCode:

```
View{

initPDFControl(){

borderControl.DoMagic();
};

openImage(String path);
}

ViewModel{

openImage(){

getMyView.openImage(pathFromModel);
}

}
```

You can help me by linking me to helpful tutorials or note down some pseudocode.

Comment: too vague for anyone to understand what you mean, the code does not help either.

Comment: That’s not valid C# code there.

Answer (score 3):

From the example you have given it looks like you are not aware of the MVVM pattern. The view (XAML) is linked to the viewmodel class. The viewModel should be unaware of any Views. But the view is aware of its viewModel. You should write the commands in viewModel and not in the model. You have to access model class from the viewModel. First understand the pattern and then go forward to coding. There are many MVVM Libraries (for eg. MVVMLight, Prism) available in Nuget, you can use them in your code.

You can look at these links for understanding the concept.

[Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained)

[WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level)

[MSDN-Implementing the MVVM Pattern Using the Prism Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx)